# Is there a way to track a GPS device using PHP?

Tags: php, asp.net, gps

In my upcoming project, I need to track GPS device attached to vehicles. Is there any way this is possible through PHP or ASP.Net

Comment: What kind of system will be taking the GPS readings? You'd need to get the data from the GPS posted off to your PHP or ASP.NET script to handle it

Comment: Does this device have a way to get a signal so it will then relay it's position to a server? How do you know, not considering a language, where the device (car) is?

Comment: @Alistair, You mean It is not possible

Comment: What language a driver is written in sort of limits your further choices. What OS is this running on?

Comment: @James, I am actually not sure, do you know of any device which sends signal to the server? I am also suppose to determine the technology as well

Comment: You, jeepies? http://thedailywtf.com/articles/you,-jeepies.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first this device have to send data somehow, then you need to capture it in some DB then present via PHP, ASP.Net or anything else. there is no such class `GPSDevice` with method `GetPosition` that will do all the magic.

Comment: "there is no such class GPSDevice with method GetPosition that will do all the magic" lol. quite naive answer

Comment: How would Low Jack (mispelled) work then?  There must be some way to send out a signal and have it then respond back with it's location.  It would be a matter of having a receiver, perhaps like a cellphone receiver, paired with a gps chip, as it could then determine the location and send an SMS message back.

Comment: it sends data via radio. Remember, GPS device itself is only **receiver**, if you want to track it you need to integrate sender device.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are "standard" protocols at the hardware level, adherence varies. And AFAIK, as yet there is no kernel support for GPS devices as standard in Linux (I'm not sure that there should be either). However you might find [gpsd](http://gpsd.berlios.de/) useful.

C.